# Using realloc with char*

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    char *cp;
    
    cp = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    cp="kerem";
    //strcpy(cp, "kerem");
    printf("%s",cp);
    cp=(char *)realloc(cp,30 * sizeof(char));
    //strcpy(cp, "kerem demir Aziz Kerem Demir");
    cp= "kerem demir Aziz Kerem Demir";
    printf("%s",cp);
    //free(cp);
 
   return 0;
}
```

While using the strcpy function, I can copy the pointer string without any problems, but; When I do this using char * I get this error: realloc(): invalid pointer

Comment: yes because you put 29 characters in 20 character space. The next 9 character spaces belong to realloc and your code steals them anyway

Comment: `cp = "kerem"`? You're not copying, you're just changing where that pointer points to. Your first allocation is thrown into the void, and leaks memory. You **cannot** `realloc()` on a pointer like that as `"kerem"` was never allocated in the first place.

Comment: Side note: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12149471)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems in this code:

- It seems you expect `cp="kerem";` to be copying the data to the location pointed to by `cp`, while in fact it just makes `cp` to point to the location of the string literal "kerem"
- Having in mind the first bullet, you are calling realloc on a pointer to string literal which is not allowed
- Even if we ignore the first two, the new size of `cp` would be 20, which is not sufficient to store the value you try to copy (even assuming you use strcpy instead of `=`).

Answer (score 1):

The crucial problem is the line:

```
cp="kerem";
```

The string literals in C works more or less (*) like this:

```
static char _unnamed_[] = "kerem";
cp = _unnamed_;
```

Now the `cp` points to a memory that *does not* originate from a dynamic allocation via `malloc`/`realloc` and it cannot be an argument for `realloc` without invoking Undefined Behavior.

That is why `strcpy` is required because it copies the content of the memory to another memory pointed by `cp`. The value of the pointer `cp` does not change.

(*) string literals cannot be modified, moreover literal with the same content *may* share the storage.